# If x is some fixed real number, for each $ n \in N $ find the sum of $1-x-x^2-x^3-...-x^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction, geometric-series

If x is some fixed real number, for each $ n \in N $ find the sum of $1-x-x^2-x^3-...-x^n$.

The problem comes from "A friendly introduction to analysis" by Kosmala 2nd ed.

My approach to solving this problem was that I recognized that this looks similar to a geometric progression, so using the help of the internet, we have $1+r+r^2+r^3+...+r^n = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$. By rearranging the original expression, I can deduce that the summation of the expression is equal to $\frac{x^{n+1}-2x+1}{1-x}$ when $x \neq 1$ and $1-n$ when $x=1$. My question is, how would I go about attaining this answer had I not used the help/prior knowledge of the formula for the summation of the geometric progression?

Comment: Why do you think there should be another way? Apart from the first term, this is a geometric sum. From now on seeing a geometric sum is like meeting an old acquaintant. You recognize them, greet them etc.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The textbook did not provide any formula, I had to search for it elsewhere. Additionally, this problem was in the section for Mathematical Induction, so I presumed that induction was needed in order to solve this problem the way the author intended.

Comment: @feonyte that’s how a lot of induction problems are done. We either get the formula through guesswork/pattern-seeing/other formulas and then write the answer where we prove it by induction. Now that you have gotten the formula, you could maybe try proving  it with induction.

Comment: What is $$\left[x + x^2 + \cdots +x^n\right] \color{red}{\times (1 - x) ~?}$$  Induction not needed here.

Comment: @user2661923 If we are pedantic you actually need induction to rigorously handle the three dots, post multiplication. Yes, the sum telescopes, but the standard induction exercises proving formulas for sums like $\sum_{k=1}^n$ and $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$ are also essentially telescoping sums. I suspect very few teachers would require an induction here (unless they want their students to practice it). I rather use telescoping to make my students learn that this is what simple induction is all about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have done it the way we derive the formula for geometric progressions:

$$S:= 1 - x - x^2 - \cdots - x^n$$
Then
$$Sx = x-x^2-x^3 - \cdots - x^{n +1}$$
Thus $$Sx - S = 2x - 1 - x^{n + 1} \implies S = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}\frac{x^{n + 1} - 2x + 1}{1 - x},&  \mbox{ if } x \neq 1\\
1- n,&  \mbox{ if } x = 1\end{array}\right.$$